# How to provide a property Bean to a Java Component in Mule Studio?

Tags: java, spring, components, mule, esb

In Mule Studio 3.5, directly in the XML and in a Flow, I have the following declaration :

```
<component class="fr.esb.bo.GenerateReportFileComponent" doc:name="BOreport">           
            <spring:property name="boServices" ref="boServices"/>
</component>
```

When I launch Mule with this, I get the following error

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'spring:property'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-interceptor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":interceptor-stack, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-entry-point-resolver-set, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-entry-point-resolver, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-object-factory, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-lifecycle-adapter-factory, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":binding}' is expected.
```

I understand that, but how can I provide my boServices bean to my component ?
With a custom-transformer, this is working well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define your class as a Spring bean:

```
<spring:beans>
  <spring:bean id="restaurantWaiter" scope="prototype" class="com.foo.RestaurantWaiter">
    <spring:property name="kitchenService">
        <spring:ref local="kitchenService"/>
    </spring:property>
  </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>

<component>
  <spring-object bean="restaurantWaiter"/>
</component>
```

as explained [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Spring+Beans+as+Flow+Components).

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer, component is not closed by the way, same in the doc.

Comment: Quick copy-pasting... :D Fixed the close tag.